# Linux C/C++ keyboard ctrl+[somekey] and ctrl+alt+[somekey}

Tags: c++, linux, key

I have been thinking how to listen keys and key combinations in Linux (and C/C++). My program structure is following:

Get text input. If ctrl + [somekey] is pressed, print text from a file called somekey.txt.
For example if you press ctrl + a the program should print the text from a file called a.txt.

If ctrl + alt + [somekey] pressed: the program saves already given (not pressed enter) text input to a file called somekey.txt. Example: ctrl+alt+a --> before typed text to file called a.txt. It should also replace the old text in the file if excist. It can be done by force-creating the file.

I have no idea which library I should use. Maybe sdl or ncurses? The program can also be written in some other languague as long as the program stays lightweight to run in Computers like Raspberry Pi.  Could someone write me a little code which follows this structure? Thanks in (code) advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go down the SDL route, it should be pretty simple. In general, your program will have a flow like this:

- [Initialize SDL](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Init)
- [Event loop](http://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryEvents)

  - [Wait for event](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WaitEvent)
  - Handle event, possibly exiting loop
- [Shut down SDL](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Quit)

In that “handle events” step, you'll probably want to check to see if the event is a keyboard event, and if it is, switch on what modifier keys are held down. Then you can perform whatever logic is necessary.

See [the documentation](http://wiki.libsdl.org/FrontPage), and in particular [the keyboard category](http://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryKeyboard) for more information.

Comment: How can I wait for a moment when excecuting the program. For example how can I wait after ctrl is pressed for alt for 50ms? Now I need to press ctrl and alt at the same time.

Comment: @user121032: I don't see how waiting has to do with anything. After all, you only care about whether control/alt is held down when they press a letter, right? So you could just have boolean variables for whether control or alt are held down and update them as appropriate; when you receive a letter key-press, check those booleans to see what else is held down.